Count unique values and group by date
I have a table like:



client_id
action
date (datetime)




1
visit
2024-10-10 10:00


1
visit
2024-10-10 12:00


1
visit
2024-10-10 13:00


2
visit
2024-10-10 13:00



So, I need to count amount of unique clients with group by date. The result should look like {'date': 2024-10-10, "count_visits": 2}.
I tried several variations with annotate(unique=True) and OuterRef, but it never worked to group by date.

Can you share the corresponding models in Django?

For pure ORM solution you should be able to use this
from django.db.models import Count
from django.db.models.functions import TruncDate

YourTable.objects.annotate(pure_date=TruncDate('your_date_field_name')).values('pure_date').annotate(count_visits=Count('client_id', distinct=True))


here is a solution working with dict following Raymond Hettinger precomandations:
from collections import defaultdict

# get the first queryset:
temp_qs = MyModel.objects.filter(
    action="visits",
    date__gte=from_date,
    date__gte=to_date,
)

# get a dict with visits for each client:
visits_dict= defaultdict(list)
for temp_val in temp_qs:
visits_dict[temp_val.client].append(temp_val)

# count what you except:
count_dict = {client : defaultdict(int) for client in visits_dict}
count_dict=defaultdict(int)
for client,visits in visits_dict.items():
    count_dict[client][visits.date]+=1

# if you really want a dict as you wrote :
your_dict = dict()
for client, date in count_dict.items():
    your_dict[client]= {
        'date': date, 
        "count_visits": count_dict[client][date]
    }

I hope it will help you !

Thx!! But maybee is there way to do this on database lvl?

An alternative to @PTomasz solution in order to obtain the desired result:
from django.db.models import Count, Value, CharField
from django.db.models.functions import Concat

YourModel.objects.values(
    timestamp=Concat(
        "date__year",
        Value("-"),
        "date__month",
        Value("-"),
        "date__day",
        output_field=CharField(),
    )
).annotate(count_visits=Count("client_id", distinct=True))

